# EOF caught while checking if connected the following from address failed (PHP mailer)

Tags: php, phpmailer

Bear with me as i will try me best to explain the scenario.I have been recently working with phpmailer.I was able to send mails using following settings week ago but now it's  giving the above error.I have read older post but still unable to find a solution.

```
<?php 
   if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
 {
   $from = $_POST['email'];
   $name = $_POST['name'];
   include("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
   $mail = new PHPMailer();
   $mail->IsSMTP();
   $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
   $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
   $mail->Host ='192.168.10.184';
 //$mail->SMTPAuth= true;
   $mail->Port = 25;
   $mail->Username= 'xyz3@gmail.com';  
   $mail->Password= '*****';           
   $mail->SMTPSecure = 'non';
   $mail->From = $from;
   $mail->FromName= $_POST['name'];
   $mail->isHTML(true);
   $mail->Subject = $_POST['subject'];
   $mail->Body = $_POST['message'];
   $to = "xyz3@gmail.com";    
   $mail->addAddress($to);
   $mail->AddReplyTo($_POST['email'], $name );
   $mail->IsHTML(true);
    if($mail->Send())
      {        
       echo '<script type="text/javascript">
       window.location = "http://localhost/abcwebsite/" </script>';
       }
    else
      { echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        window.location = "http://localhost/abcwebsite/"</script>';
       }
       }
    ?>
```

Note: i am using the correct port as well as the Host ip.

Update: The mail functionality is working fine with following setting when replaced in above code but this not required..

```
$mail->Host ='smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth=true;
$mail->Port=465; 
$mail->SMTPSecure ='ssl';
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Set `SMTPDebug=2` so you can see what the server is saying. Also `'non'` is not a valid value for `SMTPSecure`; set it to `false`.

Comment: @Synchro SMTPDebug=2 already..sorry for that above typo .secondly i changed SMTPSecure to false but the error is the same...any recommendations?

Comment: If it's not connecting at all, and you're getting no SMTP output, it suggests that you may have the wrong `Host` value. The troubleshooting guide tells you how to check the servers you're trying to connect to.